Intel unison Linux
Intel unison or like it for Linux
Hello, I am a Ubuntu user as well as a iOS user because I like those operating systems and they really work for me. But when I was on windows I used intel unison to get my message from iOS to windows. It uses bt to read and send text. That is something KDE connect lacks. So I was wondering if there any way to install Ms store apps via wine or something (because intel unison is Ms store only) or any alternative for Linux.
Thanks A lot!

Is this: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1319/gsconnect/ something similar to what you are talking about? (However, I think you are not using GNOME.)

No gs connect is any extension for KDE connect. I tried KDE connect but it lacks some of the features you can find on windows app

The WineHQ database has no record of anybody testing Unison with Wine and reporting the results. You can be the first, if you wish.

"or any alternative for Linux" Linux is not the problem. iOS is the problem. Apple could easily make iOS compatible with long-standard multi-platform tools. You paid them a great deal of money to not do that.
